# Repeating same animation for `odd and even `div` sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to become familiar with `jQuery waypoints`. I was wondering if there is anyway for me to simplify the following code. I tried to do it by checking the even/odd for `item-*` and wrap it inside a `if else` function but it did not work.

```
    $('.features-task-management-item-1').css('opacity', 0);
    $('.features-task-management-item-1').waypoint(function() {
        $('.features-task-management-item-1').addClass('fadeInLeft');
    }, { offset: '70%' });
    $('.features-task-management-item-2').css('opacity', 0);
    $('.features-task-management-item-2').waypoint(function() {
        $('.features-task-management-item-2').addClass('fadeInRight');
    }, { offset: '70%' });
    $('.features-task-management-item-3').css('opacity', 0);
    $('.features-task-management-item-3').waypoint(function() {
        $('.features-task-management-item-3').addClass('fadeInLeft');
    $('.features-task-management-item-4').css('opacity', 0);
    $('.features-task-management-item-4').waypoint(function() {
        $('.features-task-management-item-4').addClass('fadeInRight');
    $('.features-task-management-item-5').css('opacity', 0);
    $('.features-task-management-item-5').waypoint(function() {
        $('.features-task-management-item-5').addClass('fadeInLeft');

    }, { offset: '70%' });
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML using the HTML/CSS/Javascript snippets feature? You might be able to select all the children called `features-task-management-item-*` and add odd/even class then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with the Waypoints but here are my thoughts.
If you can rename the classes of elements (features-task-management-item-) to classes without numbers (features-task-management-item) then do it.
If you can't then you can use jquery [selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like this 
`$('[class^="features-task-management-item-"]')`

So the point is to use JQuery [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to go through all of the items and use an index as an even/odd marker.

```
$('.features-task-management-item').each(function(i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    var $item = $(this);
    var isEven = index % 2 == 0;
    var fadeClass = isEven ? 'fadeInRight' : 'fadeInLeft';

    $item.css('opacity', 0);
    $item.waypoint(function() {
        $item.addClass(fadeClass);
    }, { offset: '70%' });
});
```

Hope I helped you a little

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you so much, I think I get the logic now, I will build upon it.